The problem is anywhere desk was placed on my MacBook Pro 16, illegally, recently. I have removed most with Apple's help
I found an anydesk.app installed in my computer illegally, while I was gone, presumably as spyware. I was able to remove the simple app. Apple support helped me remove the hidden file, ".anydesk.app" that was still in my computer, and went through libraries and other places and I thought the problem was fixed. It is not. I went to the firewall and, sure enough, the item call com.philandro.anydesk is allowed incoming connections, in the firewall. I tried numerous times to block the file, and may have been successful this time; I"ll restart and log back in, whether it has turned itself back on  to 'allow incoming" or not, we'll see. If it does, I don't know how to get rid of it. An earlier answer here even updated about October 2023 on this location is for a different operating system. I can't find an equivalency on this newer Sonoma OS to that earlier answer. I don't find a file com.philandro.anydesk anywhere in the library or start-up file in Sys Settings but  yes, it does start up, at least, unless my most recent efforts which I'm in the middle of, I can append this later with further symptoms if I still have them.  By the way, one way I know the bad guy is using it, is the computers' fans start-up full, and only when he's interfering with me--not just watching.  Also,ALWAYS, when loading from a full power-down, the progress bar will go 1/4 way, stop, the then -start-up- tone will sound AGAIN, computer progress bar will continue to load to completion at a much faster rate. Please help me get rid of his spying and now active interference!

There is a similar question on SuperUser: How to remove Anydesk completely from my Mac after scammer tricked us into granting access.
